# comparing two strings in jquery

Tags: jquery

what's wrong with this code

```
function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'string' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'string' );



  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  }
```

it's suppose to compare 2 string from 2 different arrays and drop the right letter on the slot but it drops everything on anything like A on B

here's the code for the arrays

```
var numbers = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ];
  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );


  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'string', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }
```

and this is for the droppable elements

```
 var words = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'  ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'string', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}
```

this originally was for numbers it compares two numbers and and drop the right number on the right slot but i need letters, can somebody tell me what's wrong with it ? please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Words elements are not getting the string put into `data('string')` they are getting the number in the loop used.

Also the numbers array is shorter than the indexing you are using to set `data('string')` for those because array inex starts at zero not 1

In numbers loop change:

```
data( 'string', numbers[i] )
```

To

```
data( 'string', numbers[i-1] )
```

In words loop change

```
.data( 'string', i )
```

To

```
.data( 'string', words[i-1] )
```

What is more important though is learning how to debug things like this

Some simple `console.log(variableName)` statements would help you see why things aren't comparing properly. Save yourself a lot of time by studying some tutorials on debugging javascript

Or throwing in a `debugger` statement and inspecting the values in each step would help

Comment: it worked !! but i only edited 
.data( 'string', words[i-1] )